# Cross platform application

Tags: android, database, web, cross-platform

Me and my friend are going to work on final year project (graduation).
We are going to create an android application as well as web.
Now the problem is that we can not work together. He is far from me but we have to access a single database as android and web will get and post data to same data base.
Is is possible to create a single data base and both of us access that db?
If yes then how???
I am working on android and friend on Web
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The main idea here is to create a core code, something you can share no matter what sort of application are you building web or mobile, that means you have to start creating an API, preferably using a programming language you handle with some framework for extra help and then setting up a DB engine.

There are plenty of options you could use, eg. db4free.net for MySQL, mlab.com for MongoDB, Amazon aws or even Google Cloud offers free accounts for testing purposes and once you have your DB and API built, you can start creating the client application.